# Obtaining AzureAD Refresh token in asp.net core 2.2 mvc app

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, odata, dynamics-365

I created a asp.net core 2.2 mvc app with the default template that has authentication through work or school account added to it with the following configuration:

```
            var azureAD = config.GetSection("AzureAD").Get<AzureADSettings>();
            if (azureAD.Enabled)
            {
                services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddAzureAD(options =>
                {
                    config.Bind("AzureAd", options);
                });
                services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
                {
                    options.ResponseType = azureAD.ResponseType; //"token id_token"
                    options.Resource = azureAD.Resource; //"resource link, dynamics in my case"
                    options.SaveTokens = azureAD.SaveTokens; //"true"
                    options.Scope.Add(azureAD.Scope); //"offline_access"
                });
            }
```

In my controller I get the access token using the following code:

```
var accessToken = await _httpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
```

I then use this access token in the ODataLibrary to access data from Dynamics 365 Finance and Operations:

```
            _dataServiceContext.SendingRequest2 += new EventHandler<SendingRequest2EventArgs>(async delegate (object sender, SendingRequest2EventArgs e)
            {
                var accessToken = await dynamicsToken.GetAccessToken();
                e.RequestMessage.SetHeader(OAuthHelper.OAuthHeader, $"Bearer {accessToken}");
            });
```

It worked fine at first but then I started getting 401 Unauthorized status codes and I assume this is because the access token expired so I tried to get a new one using the refresh token:

```
var accessToken = await _httpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");

            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

            var jwtSecurityToken = tokenHandler.ReadJwtToken(accessToken);

            if (jwtSecurityToken.ValidTo < DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1))
            {
                using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
                {
                    var formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
                    {
                        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "refresh_token"),
                        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", "client id from azure ad"),
                        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", "client secret from azure ad"),
                        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("resource", "resource link"),
                        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("scope", "offline_access"),
                        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("refresh_token", await _httpContext.GetTokenAsync("refresh_token"))

                    });
                    var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token", formContent);
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                    var newAccessToken = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    return newAccessToken;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return await _httpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
            }
```

But `_httpContext.GetTokenAsync("refresh_token")` just returns null. Did I not configure it properly or what is the reason I'm not getting a refresh token?

Comment: Did you try `await HttpContext.Authentication.GetTokenAsync("refresh_token");`? And double check that you are actually requesting the scope `offline_access` like you outline in your code (`options.Scope.Add(azureAD.Scope)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the [Implicit grant flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow#send-the-sign-in-request) as response type is `token id_token` .

[image]

Your ID token and access token immediately returned to your client app from the authorize endpoint without having to make a second request to the authorize endpoint.

The implicit grant allows the app to get tokens from Microsoft identity platform without performing a backend server credential exchange , which is common used in AngularJS, Ember.js, React.js, and so on . The security characteristics of these apps are significantly different from traditional server-based web applications. Also the implicit grant [**does not** provide refresh tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow#refreshing-tokens).

If using asp.net core , it's recommended to use the [authorization code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) . You can find the code sample from:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect-aspnetcore

Note : Above  sample is for `Azure AD v1.0`. If you are looking for an `Azure AD v2.0` sample (to sign-in users with `Work and School accounts` and `Microsoft Personal accounts`, please look at [code samples](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2) .

Comment: This is correct, I've changed `options.ResponseType` to "code" and I now have both an access token and a refresh token and I was able to renew the access token. Unfortunately the OData endpoint is giving me 401 Unauthorized even with a new access token. I've tried with samples from AD 1.0 as well as AD 2.0 but the result is the same. The only way I've managed to access it so far is on .NET 4.5 with authentication through user prompt.